# Disable kerning in RMagick - ruby

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

How do I disable kerning in the `Draw#annotate` method block. I'd like to make it so each character in a string displays equal distance from each other.

Currently I am using

```
text = Draw.new
text.annotate(img, 0, 0, 0, 7, code) do
      self.gravity = NorthWestGravity
      self.kerning = 0
      self.pointsize = 10
      self.font_family = "Monospace"
      self.fill = "black"
      self.stroke = 'none'
end
```

Comment: Use `monospaced` font?

Comment: I'm using `monospace` on Linux mint but it still is kerning text.

Comment: Linuces are known to provide obsolete versions of `IM`. Furthermore, Mint might go with `GraphicsMagick` instead. Check whether your version of IM is greater or equal to `6.4.7-8`, since `-kerning` attribute appeared in [6.4.7-8 only](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#kerning). To check the version,  execute `convert --version` from console.

Comment: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 https://gist.github.com/redcodefinal/037ab62e6e57b67c9715

Comment: I found out Monospace isn't monospaced.Using Liberation Mono fixed it.